# obtaining currency exchange rate values for different coins via apis

Tags: litecoin, api, website-integration, quarkcoin

ive been trying to work out what the best way of obtaining the exchange rate of a bitcoin or any other digital currency is via online resources for a website I want to build.

I've seen this question/answer here; [Displaying price in BTC based on USD exchange rate](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12364/displaying-price-in-btc-based-on-usd-exchange-rate)

So sure thats easy but what about other coins against the dollar or against bitcoins.  Am I going to have to obtain all this info from different sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not actually trading, you can pull the price from multiple exchanges and show an average, since there is no such thing as *fixed price* for the exchange, preev.com is a nice converter that shows average of 4 sources which you can modify from the settings menu, it should give you an idea.